# R not locating or reading file

Tags: r, csv

I have an R script for running some pricing analysis. The script begins as follows.

```
currency <- function(number)
{
print(paste("€",format(number, nsmall=2, digits=2), sep=""))
}

cheap <- read.csv("cheap.csv")
expensive <- read.csv("expensive.csv")
max <- read.csv("max.csv")
fair <- read.csv("fair.csv")
```

however, when I try to run it, I get the error:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> In file(file, "rt") :
>
> cannot open file 'cheap.csv': No such file or directory

I cannot see where the issue lies. There is a file saved as "cheap.csv" in the same folder as the R script.

Comment: I've removed tag `s` as you are using R. Does anyone still use S these days?

Comment: If I setwd then it works. However I thought that it should just run from the same directory that the script is located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is a file saved as "cheap.csv" in the same folder as the R script

This is not all that relevant. What’s relevant is that the file is in the folder *from which the R script is run*. You can get the current working directory with `getwd()` and set it via `setwd`.

*If* you run your script from the folder in which it is located then your code will work without `setwd`.

Comment: Of course, I was thinking that it would run from the directory in which it was saved. I can't believe I've been so stupid.

Answer (score 2):

cannot open file 'cheap.csv': No such file or directory ...

it simply says that file cheap.csv is not there

Try getwd() and check if it correspond to your file location